# Getting error while implementing the Google API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting the following error while implementing the `google MAP` API using JavaScript.

Error:

```
**auto.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at auto.html:14
(anonymous) @ auto.html:14**
```

I am providing the code below.

auto.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent-Child Communication</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initService" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
   <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My requirement is when user will type something the places name will come in auto suggestion, but in my case it's throwing the error.

Comment: yes, but as it was trial version after searching only one data,its throwing `You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account:` error.

Comment: In that case you need to create a new `API key`, it won't load up the map otherwise

Comment: You don't need a new key, you need to enable billing on your account with a credit card.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);`, then change the script include from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initService" async defer></script>
```

to (so it calls your `init` function):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=init" async defer></script>
```

**working code snippet:**

```html
<title>Parent-Child Communication</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=init" async defer></script>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  }
</script>
```